# Extra rows in nested Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have gridview with itemtemplate columns and it generates extra tr in rendered html
i have set CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" and  AutoGenerateColumns="false", but is doesn't help..

here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" GridLines="None" runat="server"
CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" ShowFooter="true"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="Grid_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"
                class="table_sabcho">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr id="sds">
                <td><a href="show_item.aspx?id=<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "id") %>">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "number")%></a>
                </td>
                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "date","{0 :dd/MM/yyyy}")%>
                </td>

                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category")%></td>

                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type_name")%>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 0;"><%# getDoc((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")).ToString())%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></table> </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

here is how i databind grid:

```
protected void GetLastNewsGrid()
{

    String query = "Select  * from  sample_view order by id desc";
    DataSet lawdataset = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connString, CommandType.Text, query);

    GridView1.DataSource = lawdataset;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

here is rendered html  :

```
<tr id="it is empty.." >
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="sds" >
  <td><a href="show_item.aspx?id=518"> 4965/2/12 </a></td>
  <td>24.12.2012 </td>
  <td></td>
  <td>dep </td>
  <td style="padding-left: 0;"><a class="pdf_box" href="common/get_doc.aspx?docID=6900" ></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the extra tr is for header, you dont have anything in your header..

Comment: by looking your code, i dont think you need item template at all, you can just use normal datafields with header text..

Comment: i need itemtempalte because of css style. so you said that header is generated inside of Itemtempate? you can see that i have <HeaderTemplate> and <FooterTemplate> which are working properly

Comment: are you getting header of table, i mean the column names?

Comment: please try adding "ShowHeader="false".. let me know if this works